# Read an array of data to insert into a datatable

Tags: php

I have an array which contains train departure data. What I am trying to do is loop through the array
and insert each record into a database.

The issue is when I read the array I am only getting one record. Where am I going wrong?

My code:

```
$data = array();
require("OpenLDBWS.php");
    $OpenLDBWS = new OpenLDBWS("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepartureBoard(20,"GLC",0,0,30,120); 
    foreach($response->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service as $service)
    {
        foreach ($response as $value) {
                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                // insert records in to database
            }
    }
```

The array of data I am working with:

```
stdClass Object ( [GetStationBoardResult] => stdClass Object ( [generatedAt] => 2021-07-08T19:12:29.7123685+01:00 [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC [platformAvailable] => 1 [trainServices] => stdClass Object ( [service] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:45 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => EcerPly59dqz5Om5WptKdA== [rsid] => SR961200 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Largs [crs] => LAR ) ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:45 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => R8WIwBKrr5VG44stUZ1UEA== [rsid] => SR941100 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Newton [crs] => NTN [via] => via Maxwell Park ) ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:46 [etd] => On time [platform] => 17 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => L7/E80Ta2f6z2qCI/YGTJg== [rsid] => SR693100 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Larkhall [crs] => LRH ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR [via] => via Yoker ) ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:47 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => xnijYlYcM+E5zxGOlHLnkQ== [rsid] => SR907300 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => East Kilbride [crs] => EKL ) ) ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:47 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => XGSOnG/rY0DfEAgniUKkVQ== [rsid] => SR757800 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Edinburgh [crs] => EDB [via] => via Motherwell ) ) ) ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:48 [etd] => On time [platform] => 16 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => X05hqJA8cAN3NrPewryo6Q== [rsid] => SR933700 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Larkhall [crs] => LRH ) ) ) ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:50 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => c+c8//o7sx5YQ26GzaHi1g== [rsid] => SR838900 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Lanark [crs] => LNK [via] => via Bellshill & Shieldmuir ) ) ) ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:55 [etd] => Cancelled [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [isCancelled] => 1 [serviceType] => train [cancelReason] => This train has been cancelled because of a member of on train staff being taken ill [serviceID] => cM9u9ORpWdmTiCN8EAGXXQ== [rsid] => SR688800 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Motherwell [crs] => MTH ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR [via] => via Singer ) ) ) ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 19:56 [etd] => On time [platform] => 16 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => kzwZwDbuOKlSwgIIPDDElQ== [rsid] => SR686100 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Cumbernauld [crs] => CUB ) ) ) ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:04 [etd] => On time [platform] => 17 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => VoJk6LX+awhqYOqp6cnI2Q== [rsid] => SR704600 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Motherwell [crs] => MTH ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR [via] => via Yoker ) ) ) ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:06 [etd] => On time [operator] => Avanti West Coast [operatorCode] => VT [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => pauq/9t8+GHiHdFzZDn62A== [rsid] => VT184000 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Crewe [crs] => CRE ) ) ) ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:06 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => 8znnX8RPY+CaRTj2O3p2vA== [rsid] => SR868100 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Gourock [crs] => GRK ) ) ) ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:12 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => V+ACg5jRw9iq080tsvBYWg== [rsid] => SR854200 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Paisley Canal [crs] => PCN ) ) ) ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:16 [etd] => On time [platform] => 17 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => 3CyYihwXPPP94DDmL/a+Cw== [rsid] => SR933500 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Larkhall [crs] => LRH ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Garscadden [crs] => GRS ) ) ) ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:17 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => gAaRB1xr340a7MW8kiHUfw== [rsid] => SR313400 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Ardrossan Harbour [crs] => ADS ) ) ) ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:17 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => 393KsY/5uadLhA0fNSmuPw== [rsid] => SR321700 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Edinburgh [crs] => EDB [via] => via Shotts ) ) ) ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:17 [etd] => On time [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => lb/oSCEuOwwl8ywlZKj5CA== [rsid] => SR749000 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Glasgow Central [crs] => GLC ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Kilmarnock [crs] => KMK ) ) ) ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:18 [etd] => On time [platform] => 16 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => ecekVrFi8Q4lzexOGa0mHA== [rsid] => SR694600 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Larkhall [crs] => LRH ) ) ) ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:25 [etd] => On time [platform] => 17 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => wambmHj4esQVxzRmyf53+w== [rsid] => SR689000 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Cumbernauld [crs] => CUB ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR [via] => via Yoker ) ) ) ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [std] => 20:28 [etd] => On time [platform] => 16 [operator] => ScotRail [operatorCode] => SR [serviceType] => train [serviceID] => 6BHc1ySAKVZ6rODADfEKOQ== [rsid] => SR847000 [origin] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Dalmuir [crs] => DMR ) ) ) [destination] => stdClass Object ( [location] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [locationName] => Motherwell [crs] => MTH ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Is that a **private** api key?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: I'd revoke it since it's still visible [from the question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68306882/revisions).

Comment: @0stone0, I just flagged it for mods, they can redact edit history for things like this

Comment: Ahhh, didn't know that. Anyway, there probably some bots who already have indexed it so I'll still recommend renewing it, just to be sure.

Comment: OP, you're referencing the `$response` variable in your loop, but you named the loop variable `$service`. Inside the loop, use `$service` instead of `$response`.